# create a custom loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Making an attempt to teach coding to kids. I am trying to create a layer of abstraction over javascript just to simplify the syntax for the kids.

I think it will be a bit overwhelming for a kid to learn a typical while loop

Is there any way to convert

```
var i = 0 
while(i<10)
{ 
doThis(); 
doThat() 
i++
}
```

into something easier like this

```
repeat(10)
{
doThis();
doThat();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you code your own compiler, no

Comment: _"I think it will be a bit overwhelming for a kid to learn a typical while loop"_ You'd be surprised what kids can learn

Comment: @j08691 This is motivating. I am breaking my head to make things simple

Comment: With that syntax, @epascarello is correct, you'd need your own interpreter to transpile it into vanilla JavaScript. Alternatively, if syntax isn't an issue, you could just write a function called repeat where it's essentially just a wrapper for a loop.

Comment: I learned alone the for loop at 12 with my Vic20, don't underestimate children's abilities please

Comment: Have you looked into Scratch?

Comment: @alessandro. Totally agree with you but not all kids are equal. I am trying to start simple..ultimately taking them to the normal syntax.

Comment: Wasn't simplicity for kids the goal of Logo (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)) ?

Comment: @epascarello Yes but its block based. I am trying to teach text coding.

Comment: you can use whiteboards or gifs to explain the concepts, then map the concepts to the real programming syntax. I am doing this most of the time in my classes

Comment: So only way to do it would be to basically do what typescript does and transpile your form of a language to JavaScript. Issue is no IDE will know the syntax so no nice coloring or linting.

Comment: I know that you're trying to make it easier for the kids to learn coding, but at the same time, how helpful will it be for them once they pickup your customized logic/structure to then eventually go "ok, forget all that.  here is what it actually does".

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it's possible to do exactly what you want, even hacking.

However, if you want to simplify it for your students, you go about with something like this?

```
/* you can hide this function by having it imported from external JS file */
var repeat = function(num, func){
   var i = 0;
   while(i < num){ 
      func();
      i++;
   }
};

var command = function(){
   doThis(); 
   doThat();
};

repeat(10, command);
```

if you're working with modern javascript

```
const repeat = (num, func) => {
   let i = 0;
   while(i < num){ 
      func();
      i++;
   }
};

const command = () => {
   doThis(); 
   doThat();
};

repeat(10, command);
```

Comment: Thanks Jacky however there is no flexibility here which while loop has.  The command function is set to do doThis and do That. What if we have to repeat only doThis?